# How to combine 4 entity tables into one expression?

Tags: c#, join, lambda, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I need help understanding how to perform multiple joins in a Linq-to-Entities statement. I always have a very hard time understanding the expressions for Linq joins, and especially multiple joins. I always end up using sub-queries instead. For example:

```
public List<MyReportItem> GetReportItemsHelper(string[] years, string[] quarters, string[] areas, string myType, string[] ownerships, IEnumerable<String> fieldCodes)
{
    var _reportItems = _db.MytableEntity1
        .Where(c => c.FieldID.Equals(MY_ID)             //Id Field
            && years.Contains(c.PeriodYear)             //PeriodYear/Year
            && quarters.Contains(c.Period)              //Period/Quarters
            && c.MyType.Equals(myType)                  //Special Type
            && areas.Contains(c.Area)                   //Area                   
            && ownerships.Contains(c.Ownership))        //Ownership
        .Where(c => fieldCodes.Contains(c.FieldCode))   //Field Code
        .Where(c => c.Suppress.Equals("0"))             //Suppression is false
        .Select(c => new MyReportItem
        {
            Field1 = c.FieldA,
            Field2 = c.FieldB,
            Field3 = c.FieldC.TrimEnd(),

            //Sub-queries
            Field4 = _db.MytableEntity2.Where(g => g.FieldID.Equals(c.FieldID) && g.MyType.Equals(c.MyType) && g.Area.Equals(c.Area)).Select(g => g.AreaName.TrimEnd()).FirstOrDefault(),
            Field5 = _db.MytableEntity3.Where(o => o.Ownership.Equals(c.Ownership)).Select(o => o.OwnerTitle.TrimEnd()).FirstOrDefault(),                   
            Field6 = _db.MytableEntity4.Where(i => c.FieldCode.Equals(i.FieldCode) && myType.Equals(c.MyType)).Select(i => i.FieldTitle).FirstOrDefault(),
            Field7 = _db.MytableEntity4.Where(i => c.FieldCode.Equals(i.FieldCode) && myType.Equals(c.MyType)).Select(i => i.FieldLevel).FirstOrDefault(),

            Field8 = c.FieldD,
            Field9 = c.FieldE,
            Field10 = c.FieldF,
            Field11 = c.FieldG,
            Field12 = c.FieldH,
            Field13 = c.FieldI,
            Field14 = c.FieldJ,
            Field15 = c.FieldK
        }).Distinct().ToList();

    return _reportItems; //return report detail items
}
```

But now I am faced with a very large database (maybe 60 million records or more?) and the sub-queries are bottlenecking our response times. I would like to fix that and make use of "joins". I see many examples showing how to perform Joins, but I hardly see any examples with *multiple* joins.

How can I perform multiple joins (within the new 'MyReportItem') on 'MytableEntity2', 'MytableEntity3', 'MytableEntity4', to eliminate the sub-queries for fields 4-7? How do I combine 4 entity tables into one expression? Thank you!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41274884/2557128 but note that normally in EF you should not need to use joins at all, you should have navigation properties on the primary object to pull in the other related objects (tables).

Comment: @NetMage do you have an example? When I do the joins before the select, it breaks my select. Specifically, .Select(c => new MyReportItem { }) no longer works as expected. Can you show how it would work?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "no longer works as expected" means? I see you have `FirstOrDefault` on your sub-queries, which could be treated differently in a `Join`.

Comment: @NetMage "you should not need to use joins at all, you should have navigation properties on the primary object to pull in the other related objects (tables)." care to elaborate on that statement? I don't even know what you mean.

Comment: [Entity Framework Relationships and Navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: @NetMage "no longer works as expected" means that things like "= c.FieldD" no longer resolves.

Comment: @NetMage I like your link but it's not showing how to solve this with Join. I'd rather avoid re-designing my model. My database is sealed completely and I cannot modify it at all.

Comment: You shouldn't need to change your database. If you don't want to change your entities, then you will need to use `Join`. BTW, note that you have redundant tests against `myType` in your subqueries for `MytableEntity4`.

Comment: @NetMage yes, I am aware of it. Thanks for pointing it out and reminding me. I have made great progress! Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupJoin` to perform the same as the sub-queries with `FirstOrDefault`. Note that if you know that each sub-query results in 1 match, you could use `Join` instead without `FirstOrDefault`.

```
var rpt = MytableEntity1
        .Where(c => c.FieldID.Equals(MY_ID)             //Id Field
            && years.Contains(c.PeriodYear)             //PeriodYear/Year
            && quarters.Contains(c.Period)              //Period/Quarters
            && c.MyType.Equals(myType)                  //Special Type
            && areas.Contains(c.Area)                   //Area                   
            && ownerships.Contains(c.Ownership))        //Ownership
        .Where(c => fieldCodes.Contains(c.FieldCode))   //Field Code
        .Where(c => c.Suppress.Equals("0"))             //Suppression is false
        .GroupJoin(MytableEntity2, c => new { c.FieldID, c.MyType, c.Area }, g => new { g.FieldID, g.MyType, g.Area }, (c, gj) => new { c, g = gj.Select(g => g.AreaName.TrimEnd()).FirstOrDefault() })
        .GroupJoin(MytableEntity3, cg => cg.c.Ownership, o => o.Ownership, (cg, oj) => new { cg.c, cg.g, o = oj.Select(o => o.OwnerTitle.TrimEnd()).FirstOrDefault() })
        .GroupJoin(MytableEntity4, cgo => cgo.c.FieldCode, i => i.FieldCode, (cgo, ij) => new { cgo.c, cgo.g, cgo.o, i = ij.FirstOrDefault() })
        .Select(cgoi => new MyReportItem {
            Field1 = cgoi.c.FieldA,
            Field2 = cgoi.c.FieldB,
            Field3 = cgoi.c.FieldC.TrimEnd(),
            Field4 = cgoi.g,
            Field5 = cgoi.o,
            Field6 = cgoi.i.FieldTitle,
            Field7 = cgoi.i.FieldLevel,
            Field8 = cgoi.c.FieldD,
            Field9 = cgoi.c.FieldE,
            Field10 = cgoi.c.FieldF,
            Field11 = cgoi.c.FieldG,
            Field12 = cgoi.c.FieldH,
            Field13 = cgoi.c.FieldI,
            Field14 = cgoi.c.FieldJ,
            Field15 = cgoi.c.FieldK
        }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between GroupJoin and Join? This is awesome. I haven't implemented GroupJoin (yet) but the regular Joins have improved the response time tremendously!

Comment: This is what I was really after: c => new { c.FieldID, c.MyType, c.Area }, it seems that I couldn't wrap my head around it until now. This is awesome, thank you!!

Comment: `Join` will only return a result if both left and right hand sides have a match (inner join), and will return one result per left+right combination. `GroupJoin` lets you combine one left + an `IEnumerable` of all matching rights and can be used to simulate left outer join or join+group by.

Comment: this really helped me alot, and my colleagues are still scratching their heads...